# Different logs with the same configuration

Tags: matlab, logging, matlab-figure, simulink

please help to resolve this problem
all data in the attached photos are ''Limit data points to last [40001, 20]'' in Matlab, but different logs, why ??
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUtRr.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjgyX.png)

I want to draw a graphic from the logged data, but different data logs make it impossible

Answer (score 0):

Are the signals at the same rate?  You have some being recorded with 40k+1 points and others with 2k+1 points, which would be consistent with some signals operating at 20x the rate of others (or perhaps a larger multiplier, if you are throwing points away by only keeping the last 40k+1 points).  So for example, part of the model operating at 100 Hz and another part operating at 5 Hz.  Changing the "Sample time" parameter on the mask of the To Workspace block may let you override this.

It is possible (in a way) to crossplot the datasets with different points, but you have to first do something to make them have the same number of points.  That of course means first figuring out why they have a different number of points.  If my theory is correct and they are just operating at different rates, then you can use `interp1()` on the "slower" data (preferably with the "previous" method).